# Feature detector vs dense detector

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection

What is the difference between a feature detector and a dense detector in computer vision? Are they the same or a subset of one another?

For the following algorithms (implemented in OpenCV), which of them are feature detectors and/or dense detectors?

- SIFT
- SURF
- AGAST
- KAZE
- AKAZE
- FAST
- BRISK
- ORB
- GFTT
- HarrisLaplace
- StarDetector

Comment: I know what a feature detector is (roughly so), but what's a *dense detector*? Can you link to a usage of that term?

Comment: I was reading [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01461562/document) paper and the authors mention **Dense Detector**, even in other papers they mention **Dense Feature Detector**. And, I've already googled but didn't find any concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

> For class matching, Hietanen in [29] compares several
> binary descriptors and SIFT with different detectors, including
> a dense grid. SIFT preformed better than other descriptors and
> dense grid responds very well.
>
> This result leads us to test dense detector for different
> descriptors…

It seems that a dense detector is one that uses a dense grid on which to evaluate some feature metric.

This is opposed to "classical" feature detectors that *search* the image for points with features.

Frankly, spanning a grid over an image to reduce it to a lower resolution does sound like what I'd call a subsampling and image transform, but maybe I'm misunderstanding this!